# Android: How to find SurfaceView touch position when fixed Size is set?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a SurfaceView for Android Game development which has `holder.setFixedSize(1280, 720);`. Added few sprites on it. I want to do some action when a sprite touched. Following is my `SurfaceView.onTouch` code where I am getting `x and y` value of the screen instead of surface view XY.

Please help me to find out actual XY of the surface view.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            if (scenes.size() > 0) {
                Scene scene = scenes.get(scenes.size() - 1);
                if (scene != null) {
                    int size = scene.getSprites().size();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Surface Touched. size : " + size);
                    for (int j = size - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                        Sprite s = scene.getSprites().get(j);
                        if (s.isTouchable() && s.performTouch(x, y)) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Touch handled by sprite");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the computation of `x` and `y` as shown below:

```
int x = (int) (event.getX() * 1280 / view.getWidth());
int y = (int) (event.getY() * 720 / view.getHeight());
```

Comment: Ideally this is the solution. but `view.getWidth()` and `view.getHeight()` return 1280 and 720 respectively so no change in the resultant XY. In order to fix this issue I kept the surfaveview `actualX` and `actualY` value before `setFixedSize()`, then replace `view.getWidth()` with `actualX` and `view.getHeight()` with actualY. It solve my issue. Thanks for your help. Please update the answer accordingly.